# Ubuntu stops working after I log back in from Sleep

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox, shutdown, freeze

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in VirtualBox Version 7.0.6 on Windows 11. Whenever my laptop goes to sleep while Ubuntu is active, after pressing a button and waking it up, my VirtualBox screen shrinks like this :

[image: a screenshot of how my screen shrinks]

Before logging back in, everything is ok. I can select my user, enter my password and log in. But after that, everything stops working as shown in the image. No button works, I can't open the terminal or anything. I can only move the mouse.

The only option I have, is to shut the system down. However, it won't even shutdown by using the *Send the shutdown signal* option. My only option is to *Power off the machine*, like plugging it out.